# How can I return the value of an Input Field when I click on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, flask-wtforms

In my template I have an input field:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="WCPO_Pesquisa" name="WCPO_Pesquisa" onchange="myFunction()" tabindex="2" type="text" value="">
```

A button:

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-sm green-seagreen tooltips" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Executa a Pesquisa na Base de Dados" tabindex="3" > 
    <a class="textobranco semtextdecoration" href="{{ url_for('EW_MP_0060_reunioes.Busca_Registro_0060', WCodigoChaveP = 'myFunction()' ) }}" hreflang="pt-br"> 
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i> 
        Exec. 
    </a>
</button>
```

And a script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x;

    //Get the value of input field with id="WCPO_Pesquisa"

    x = document.getElementById("WCPO_Pesquisa").value;

    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = x;

    return x;
}
</script>
```

I need to return the value of the input field to my view when the user click the button but I don't know how.

The value **must be assigned** to the WCodigoChaveP to be passed as an argument to my view.

I added a:

```
<p id="resultado">
```

element to my form and then added:

```
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = x;
```

on the script just to test. Its working. Whatever I type in the input filed I see on the p element.

As you can see I'm new in all this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple concept of your question.

**HTML**

```
<input  id="WCPO_Pesquisa" type="text" value="" >
<button id="go">GO!</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

**JS**

```
$("#go").click(function() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("WCPO_Pesquisa").value;
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = x;
});
```

**EDIT**

**[DEMO 1 - using form tags](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/besLoyx8/2/)**

Comment: This was already working. That's why I added the p element, to test. My problem is how do I pass the value of the inputbox as a parameter to the view when the button is clicked:    href="{{ url_for('EW_MP_0060_reunioes.Busca_Registro_0060', WCodigoChaveP = 'myFunction()' ) }}". I must return the value of the input box in the WCodigoChaveP parameter.

Comment: @user3524115 so when you press the `button`, you want it to take along the `input`? Well you can do a couple of things such as wrap this in `<form>` tags, and change `button` to `<input>` with `type="submit"`. See updated post.

Comment: Yes, I want the value of the input filed to be passed as a parameter to the view I am calling with the button. The view in this case has a function that retreave data from my DB and then calls another view which is going to render a template with the data...

Comment: well right now if you use something like php, then that demo I posted will work. Otherwise I need to see how things are being received. Otherwise you gotta pass it something else? like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/besLoyx8/3/)**. How is your page going to this new View anyways?

Comment: I'm using Pyhton with Flask. My view is going to be something like this:    @EW_MP_0060_reunioes.route('/Busca_Registro_0060', methods=['GET'])

def Busca_Registro_0060():
 
 WCodigoChaveP = request.args.get('WDadoPesq')    
 
 # Here I'll have some database sql witch will return 
 # a List with records I want to show to the user 
 
 return redirect(url_for('EW_MP_0060_reunioes.EW_MP_0060_TP', WNew_List_Records = WNew_List_Records ))